# chrome webrtc turn off all signal processing

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to disable all signal processing in chrome, but even with all the constraints turned on the audio recorded from the `getUserMedia` function still is not as clear compared to the audio recorded directly from my microphone using PyAudio.

Here are all the constraints I am defining:

```
    mandatory: {
        echoCancellation: false,
        googEchoCancellation: false,
        googAutoGainControl: false,
        googAutoGainControl2: false,
        googNoiseSuppression: false,
        googHighpassFilter: false,
        googTypingNoiseDetection: false,
    },
```

I've read the other posts about this topic (both on SO and Google forums) but still can't kill all the google signal processing.

Is there a way to just get the raw audio *before* it is chewed up by Google's signal processing?

Comment: Did you try using the [new constraints syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Parameters)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Auto Gain Conctrol with WebRTC App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326846/disabling-auto-gain-conctrol-with-webrtc-app)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I did use the new constraints syntax; still getting some distortion in the signal. It's definitely better than with no constraints, but still sounds like it went through some processing.